# jQuery pass element value to dropdown option text

Tags: jquery, nodes, html-select

The div container:

```
<div id="count"><span>Apple:</span>4</div>
```

The form dropdown list:

```
<select id="list" size="6">
  <option selected="selected">Any Number</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5+</option>
</select>
```

I want to tie the option list to the fruit count. If the div container has a value of "Apple:4", then "Option 4" will be selected, if the div value changes to "Pear:3" then "Option 3" should be selected, so on and so forth.

Here is what I have done so far in jQuery:

```
var optionObject = document.getElementById('list');
var countValue = document.getElementById("count").childNodes[2].nodeValue;
                
for(var i=0; i<optionObject.length; i++){                        
   if(optionObject.options[i].text == countValue.trim()){
        optionObject.options[i].selected = true;
        break;
   }
}
```

But nothing happens after execution.

Comment: did you enclose it in `$(document).ready` ??

Comment: Linking it the other way around makes more sense. Why is this tagged as jQuery if there's no jQuery in your question?

Comment: Yes, it's executed after document ready.

Comment: @user1824996 hm.. check out my answer. Just a single character mistake in your code ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works, just change the second line to:

```
var countValue = document.getElementById("count").childNodes[1].nodeValue;
```

The working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9QUsL/).

Think upon it if you have it make it work for numbers > 5 ;)

Comment: Humm, I thought I should use childNodes[2], guess I was wrong. You're right, >5 is the next thing I need to work on. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
​var a = $('#count').text();
a = a.substr(a.length - 1, a.length);
$('#list option:eq('+a+')').prop('selected','selected');
​
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/atif089/DYg96/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#list option:eq('+($('#count').text().split(':').pop())+')').prop('selected','selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/3pjbb/3/

I would suggest to use it as this:

```
var countValue = $.trim($('#count').text().match(/(\d+)/g));
$('#list').val(countValue);​
```